# database returns nil for definitely existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this controller that i very quickly put to together to direct incoming calls from a twilio phone number. I built the app and tested the code using ngrok and everything was working fine. I uploaded it to my digital ocean droplet and things are now not working as they where on my local environment. Im am getting what is apparently an error caused by having something set to nil which my code accounts for i think. Anyway here is the code and the error that triggers it. I'll put the code in question up first followed by the error message followed by my entire controller file.the line private is on line 213 i put the opNum method in private so i could call it from other methods in the same controller

```
private
def opNum
aviOperators = Operator.where(working: true).find_each
list = []
aviOperators.each do |o|
  list.push(o.calls.last)
end
list.sort! {|a, b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at}
if list.empty?
  false
else
  Operator.find(list.first.operator_id).phoneO
end
end
```

I, [2017-04-18T16:43:30.226384 #2019]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 215ms (ActiveRecord: 10.3ms)
F, [2017-04-18T16:43:30.229647 #2019] FATAL -- :
NoMethodError (undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/voice_controller.rb:220:in`block in opNum'
  app/controllers/voice_controller.rb:220:in `sort!'
  app/controllers/voice_controller.rb:220:in`opNum'
  app/controllers/voice_controller.rb:69:in `findOp'

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
class VoiceController < ApplicationController
  include Webhookable

  after_filter :set_header

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  URL = "http://botnc.com"

  def recive
    num = params['From']
    sid = params['CallSid']
    Call.create(:phoneC => num, :callSid => sid)

      response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Gather :numDigits => '1', :action => "/voice/findOp", :method => 'post', :timeout => 5 do |g|
        g.Play "#{URL}/assets/mp1.mp3"
                end
              end

            render_twiml response
  end

  def lang
    sid = params['CallSid']
    lang = params['Digits']
    call = Call.find_by_callSid( sid )  ##find_each might search through the whole db. try and make it so the DB is searched from the end towards the front
    id = call.read_attribute('id')
    Call.find(id).update(lang: lang)
   response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
       r.Enqueue "Wait"
     end

            render_twiml response

  end

  def retrive
    if opNum == false
     response =Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
                  r.Play "#{URL}/assets/waitOp.mp3"
                  end

                render_twiml response
      else
              response =Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
                r.Leave
                        end
                      render_twiml response
    end


  end

  def findOp
    sid = params['CallSid']
    lang = params['Digits']
    call = Call.find_by_callSid( sid )  ##find_each might search through the whole db. try and make it so the DB is searched from the end towards the front
    id = call.read_attribute('id')
    Call.find(id).update(lang: lang)
      #aviOperators = Operator.where(working: true).find_each
      #list = []
      #aviOperators.each do |o|
        #list.push(o.calls.last)
        #end
      #list.sort! {|a, b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at}

      if opNum == false
        response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
          r.Enqueue "Wait", waitUrl: "#{URL}/voice/retrive/"
          r.Redirect "#{URL}/voice/polishCall/"
          #r.Gather :numDigits => '1', :action => '#{URL}/assets/wait.xml', :method => 'get', :timeout => 8 do |g|
            #g.Say "Press one to hold for the next represenative"
          end 

          #r.Dial '+1'+@operators
          #end
          render_twiml response
      else
      response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|  
     r.Redirect "#{URL}/voice/polishCall/"
       end
       render_twiml response
      end
  end

  def collectCard
    cardId = params["Digits"]
    @card = Card.find_by_pinNum(cardId)
    value = 0.0
    if @card == nil
      response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|  
          r.Play "#{URL}/assets/invalidCard.mp3"
           r.Play "#{URL}/assets/goodbye.mp3"
       end
       render_twiml response
    else
    value = @card.cValue.to_f
    if value > 0.0
      sid = params["CallSid"]
      @call = Call.find_by_callSid(sid)
      id = @card.id
      @call.update(card_id: id)
      value.to_s
      response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|  
          r.Say  "Tienes #{value} dolares en tu tarjeta", :language  => "es"
           r.Play "#{URL}/assets/waitOp.mp3"
           r.Dial opNum, :action => "#{URL}/voice/finish/"  #This is where you need to put the action url to update the call with duration and the card with consumption
       end
       render_twiml response
    else
      response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|  
          r.Play "#{URL}/assets/noMinutes.mp3"
          r.Play "#{URL}/assets/goodbye.mp3"
           #r.Play "#{URL}/assets/goodbye.mp3"
       end
       render_twiml response
     end
    end



  end
  def finish
    duration = params["DialCallDuration"].to_i / 60 + 1
    sid = params["CallSid"]
    @call = Call.find_by_callSid(sid)
    @call.update(fDuration: duration )
    @card = Card.find_by_id(@call.card_id)
    newvalue = @card.cValue - (duration * 0.5)
    @card.update(cValue: newvalue)
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Say "Tienes #{newvalue} dinero pendiente", :language => "es" 
      end
    render_twiml response



  end

  def sales
    if Operator.find(1).working
      response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
        r.Dial "+19197634923"
        end
      render_twiml response
    else
      response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
        r.Say "Lo siento por favor llame a lunes entre 8 y 5", :language => "es" 
        r.Play "#{URL}/assets/goodbye.mp3"#
      end
      render_twiml response
  end
end
  def polishCall
    sid = params["CallSid"]
    lang = Call.find_by_callSid(sid).lang
    numOp = opNum
    opId = Operator.find_by_phoneO(opNum).id
    Call.find_by_callSid(sid).update(operator_id: opId)
    if lang == "2"
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Dial "+1#{numOp}" #this may be causing Problem
            end

            render_twiml response
        elsif lang == "1"
          response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
            r.Gather :numDigits => '1', :action => "#{URL}/voice/menue/", :method => 'post', :timeout => 10 do |g|
              g.Play "#{URL}/assets/menue.mp3"#the menue Audio audio
            end
          end
          render_twiml response
            else
              response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
                r.Say "You did'nt let use know what language you speak"
                    end
                    render_twiml response
                  end
  end
  def menue
    menue = params["Digits"]
    if menue == "1"
      response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
        r.Gather :numDigits => '7', :action => "#{URL}/voice/collectCard/", :method => 'post', :timeout => 10 do |g|
          g.Play "#{URL}/assets/CaptureCard.mp3"#the menue Audio audio
        end
      end
      render_twiml response
    elsif menue == "2"
      response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
        r.Gather :numDigits => '1', :action => "#{URL}/voice/sales/", :method => 'post', :timeout => 10 do |g|
          g.Play "#{URL}/assets/services.mp3"#the Services itemes and phone number for sales
        end
      end
      render_twiml response
    elsif menue == "3"
      response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
          r.Play "#{URL}/assets/storeList.mp3"
          r.Play "#{URL}/assets/goodbye.mp3"
        end
        render_twiml response
    else
      response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
          r.Play "#{URL}/assets/goodbye.mp3"
        end
        render_twiml response
    end
  end


  private
  def opNum
    aviOperators = Operator.where(working: true).find_each
    list = []
    aviOperators.each do |o|
      list.push(o.calls.last)
    end
    list.sort! {|a, b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at}
    if list.empty?
      false
    else
      Operator.find(list.first.operator_id).phoneO
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: `o.calls.last` is `nil` for at least one item.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. If you can't figure it out, step away and come back to it later, the answers are there. So the problem was that my `opNum` method looked at each of my operators and the calls assigned to them from previous instances. Well since it was a fresh database. none of my operators had calls attributed to them so that's why I got a nil on the created at query. Seeded the database with some calls and bam works